# GNU parallel with Perl expression; zsh: parse error near `}'

Tags: bash, macos, perl, zsh, gnu-parallel

Trying to run this example command (from the man page):

```
seq 10 | parallel echo {} + 1 is {= '$_++' =}
```

I get the error

```
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

How can I fix this and use `{=perl expression=}` replacement strings in my parallel commands?

I'm in iTerm 2 on macOS, using zsh.

Comment: You could try `—parens ,,,,` and then use `,, ‘$_++’ ,,`

Comment: @MarkSetchell wow, worked perfectly first time. Do you want to add it as an answer?

Comment: I think @chepner’s is a better, more legible solution than mine, but may add it as an answer when I am back near a computer. I’m voting for his ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell chepner's didn't work. I didn't tell them that it didn't work because they deleted their answer too quickly, so maybe they figured that out for themselves. Should I add your comment as an answer then or wait for you? I'm not so sure of the etiquette.

Comment: Go ahead and put it as an answer - you're welcome. I am kind of offline as I am building a new desk and decorating my office - sigh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks to [@MarkSetchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell))

This worked perfectly for me:

```
seq 10 | parallel --parens ,,,, echo {} + 1 is ,, '$_++' ,,
```

Setting `--parens` to `,,,,` and then quoting the perl expression as `,,perl expression,,`.

Answer (score 4):

As with any command, quote whatever `zsh` will try to interpret itself if left unquoted.

```
seq 10 | parallel 'echo {} + 1 is {= $_++ =}'
```

In this case, `parallel` is just going to join the various elements into a single string, *then* subject it to its own parsing, before passing the result to a shell; you may as well just pass a single string to start.

Comment: More generally, the `=}` seems to be what zsh is treating specially; it should be enough to quote just that: `seq 10 | parallel echo {} + 1 is {= '$_++' '=}'`. It happens that `parallel` doesn't care whether it receives one argument with embedded spaces or several arguments, but other commands might.

Comment: Ah, right; it's trying to expand `=}` to the full path where `}` is found in a `PATH` directory. On principle, though, you don't want any of this expression subject to shell expansion, so you may as well be explicit about what you want to be passed to `parallel`.

Comment: It is a matter of taste, but I would write it like: `seq 10 | parallel echo '{}' + 1 is '{= $_++ =}'`